# RichTextBox - Line breaks between TextRanges

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I'm having a small issue with the RichTextBox.

I'm trying to do some sort of chat including different colors each line and that's why I use the RichTextBox instead of the normal one. But I am having some trouble with line breaks.

My goal is to achieve this format:

```
Player 1: Hello world!
System Bot: The game has begun!
Player 2: sup man?
Player 1: Nothing
```

Unfortunately my code somehow isn't doing its job so far:

```
public void Handle(NewMessageMessage message)
{
    var messageStr = message.Message;

    var range = new TextRange(ChatMessages.ContentEnd, ChatMessages.ContentEnd);

    switch (message.Type)
    {
        case MessageType.SystemInformation:
            range.Text = string.Concat("System-Bot: ", messageStr, "\r\n");
            range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 150, 0)));
            break;
        case MessageType.SystemWarning:
            range.Text = string.Concat("System-Bot: ", messageStr, "\r\n");
            range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
            break;
        case MessageType.PlayerMessage:
            range.Text = string.Concat(messageStr, "\r\n");
            range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
            break;
    }

    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ChatMessages);

    TriggerScrollViewerScroll = true;
}
```

The code is not giving me the result I expected:

```
Player 1: Hello world!System Bot: The game has begun!

Player 2: sup man?

Player 1: Nothing
```

Leaving out the \r\n gives me this:

```
Player 1: Hello world!System Bot: The game has begun!Player 2: sup man?Player 1: Nothing
```

My RichTextBox looks like this:

```
<controls:ChatRichTextBox Document="{Binding ChatMessages}"  IsReadOnly="True" Margin="5"/>
```

Someone knows what's going on there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the "\r" instead of the "\r\n".

The problem is with the "\r\n" is it indicates a new paragraph. By default, paragraphs have margin in the RichTextBox. If you set the paragraphs' margin to 0 the "\r\n" will work (or the Environment.NewLine will work as well).
Set the margin something like this in your xaml:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin"
                    Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, thank you, this is working fine :)